# Unicode dingbat character that looks like a shield

Tags: html, unicode

I need to display a visual cue along with a user's name to indicate that the user is an administrator (e.g. a SO moderator's username has a diamond next to it). I searched for "administrator icon" on Google for some inspiration and decided to display a "shield" character (the one you see in Windows 7 to indicate that the action requires administrator privileges).

I do not plan to use images. Is there an ASCII/Unicode character for this?

Comment: not too hard to browse the unicode pages ;)...a word of warning, though: not all browser display all of the more exotic unicode characters. especial IE8 knows only a rather small set of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the Notepad++ character panel, and the closest to a shield I found was this: ø (ASCII code 248), or in a bigger version: Ø (ASCII code 216). Other than that, I found several designs that include multiple ASCII characters, such as:

http://www.ascii-art.de/ascii/s/shield.txt

http://www.geocities.com/spunk1111/mythical.htm#shield2

http://www.retrojunkie.com/asciiart/weapons/shields.txt

But I guess those won't be very useful to you. That was my best take at it. Anyway you can check a full ASCII reference at http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

EDIT: I found a unicode symbol that you might like: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26e8/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps ☗, rotated upside down with css transforms?

Answer (score 1):

⛉   9929    ⛉   26C9        TURNED WHITE SHOGI PIECE

⛊   9930    ⛊   26CA        TURNED BLACK SHOGI PIECE

[Black Shield](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26ca/index.htm)

[White Shield](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26c9/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

LOL, what does a dingbat character look like?.. How about using plain vanilla ASCII, like (A) = Administrator, (U) = User, etc.?.. or use sharp (#) for admin and dollar ($) for user, just like a Linux command prompt is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

In the years since this question was asked, Unicode has been updated many many times.
There are now official glyphs for shields:

## ⛨ = [U+26E8](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+26E8) black cross on shield

## = [U+1F6E1](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F6E1) shield emoji

## ️ = also [shield emoji](https://emojiterra.com/shield/)

(with modifiers that I don't understand)